# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn' to 'string'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

I have this column in SQL Server that has value of "dog,cat,mouse" so I want to fetch this data into SSIS then transform it into an array so I can loop through it but I'm having an error when doing so.

```
var columnfromDB = "1,2,3"; // Need population so that Split won't throw an error
if (Row.Animals != null)
{
columnfromDB = Row.Animals; // This is where the error comes from since Row.Animal is a BlobColumn

string[] splittedString = columnfromDB.Split(',');
}
```

But I am getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn' to 'string'

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Judging by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.blobcolumn?view=sqlserver-2019), you're adding data as binary, so you'd presumably need to use `GetBlobData` to extract the column's data, and then use the correct string encoding (the same one you used to convert text->byte[] in the first place) to convert the resulting `byte[]` into a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `BlobColumn` to `byte[]` before parse it to `string` like that:

```
var blobLength = Convert.ToInt32(Row.Animals.Length);
var blobData = Row.Animals.GetBlobData(0, blobLength);
columnfromDB = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blobData);
```